# Autocomplete returning null result in Vtiger

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vtiger

When I want to create an invoice in Vtiger I go to Invoice > Add Invoice
Scroll down to the Item details. Normally when starting to type in the field labeled "Type to search", the products should show but they are not showing (I get "No Results found"). Same applies for Quotes and Sales Orders. I am trying now to debug, so I opened Firebug when typing and in the console I get response `{"success":true,"result":[]}` and the POST Source: search_module=Products&search_value=Test&module=Invoice&action=BasicAjax, I tried searching in the module `modules/invoice/Invoice.php` Invoice the sql query that is selecting the table for getting the result but did not find anything, found only this https://github.com/clandmeter/vtiger/blob/master/modules/Invoice/views/Edit.php I am using Vtiger 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the product is not active. Please check whether the product is Active or Not, While creating a Product there you can see a check box  called "**Product Active**", Make sure you have ticked that

[image]

I don't have much reputation to put this in comment, So i added it as Answer

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I think that is the problem, I don't see any checkbox to make product active. When I create a product I go to Menu->Products->Add Product http://postimg.org/image/5tixjrk0p/

Comment: It seems you have Customized the Product module. Running this script[1] will create the Product Active Field

[1] [link](http://pastebin.com/UnJAbjS8)